# i have this list and my for loop that only show odd numbers of list but i want it show only 5 first odd number and if there is not 5 show all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

the code:

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87,
            23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
for items in num_list:
    if items % 2 != 0:
        print(items)
```

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x%2!=0, num_list))[:5]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can get what you want by adding a counter like this:

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

counter = 0

for num in num_list:
    if num % 2 != 0 and counter < 5:
        print(num)
        counter += 1
```